# Cant clear canvas in if else statements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I initialize a shape that looks like this with the `draw` function: [image]

I want to have the "a" key rotate the "gun" (red) around the "body" (blue) 4  times in a counter-clockwise manner. Such that after one "a" key press it would look like this: [image]

Then after two more rotations it would be the same.

What I am getting after 3 "a" key presses is this: [image]

Obviously I am having trouble with clearing the canvas between each a key press.
Here is my html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Game</title>
<body>
<canvas id = "arena" width = "500" height = "500">
</canvas>
<style>
canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
</body>
```

Here is my JS

```
<script type='text/javascript' id='lt_ws'     src='http://localhost:5678/socket.io/lighttable/ws.js'></script>
<script>
var gunInitialX = 100
var gunInitialY = 100
var bodyInitialX = 100
var bodyInitialY = 100
var gunFillStyle = "blue"
var bodyFillStyle = "red"
var gunInitialWidth = 8
var gunInitialLength = 1
var gun = new Path2D();
gun.rect(gunInitialX,gunInitialY,gunInitialWidth,gunInitialLength);
var body = new Path2D();
body.arc(bodyInitialX,bodyInitialY,5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
var c =
document.getElementById("arena").getContext("2d");
function draw() {

c.fillStyle = gunFillStyle
c.fill(gun);
c.fillStyle = bodyFillStyle
c.fill(body);
}
draw()

window.addEventListener("keypress", controlTank, false);
function controlTank(e){

if (e.charCode == "97" && gunInitialY == 100 && gunInitialX == 100) {
c.clearRect(0, 0, arena.width, arena.height);
gunInitialX = 100
gunInitialY = 92
gunInitialLength = 8
gunInitialWidth = 1
gun.rect(gunInitialX,gunInitialY,gunInitialWidth,gunInitialLength);
draw()
}
else if (e.charCode == "97" && gunInitialY == 92) {
c.clearRect(0, 0, arena.width, arena.height);
gunInitialX = 92
gunInitialY = 100
gunInitialLength = 1
gunInitialWidth = 8
gun.rect(gunInitialX,gunInitialY,gunInitialWidth,gunInitialLength);
draw()

}
else if (e.charCode == "97" && gunInitialX == 92) {
c.clearRect(0, 0, arena.width, arena.height);
gunInitialX = 100
gunInitialY = 101
gunInitialLength = 8
gunInitialWidth = 1
gun.rect(gunInitialX,gunInitialY,gunInitialWidth,gunInitialLength);
draw()
}
}
</script>
```

Within each `if else` block I am using `c.clearRect(0, 0, arena.width, arena.height);` But somehow my previous shapes are being drawn. I have now turned to stack overflow.

Comment: The old gun rect(s) are being kept in the gun (Path2D) - Above the gun.rect lines in controlTank function add **gun = new Path2D();** This is probably not the best approach

Comment: So i put c.beginPath before each draw() call I put the gun.rect calls within the controlTank function and I'm not seeing any changes. Is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Nope sorry, I misread your code, since you are using Path2d constructor, then @smcd is totally right, you need to reinitialise it by calling `new Path2d()`

Comment: @Kaiido So you mean re-initializing before every c.clearRect call?

Comment: reinitialise in each `controlTank` call yes. But then, I'm not sure the use of a `Path2D` object for such a simple and changing path is usefull. You may want to convert it back to old drawing methods directly on the context instead (with `beginPath()` before each new drawing sequence.) Or since what you do is just to rotate the path, you could also try to play with context's transformations (`ctx.translate` + `ctx.rotate`)

Comment: @MaxwellChandler here's a fiddle with the **new Path2D()** added https://jsfiddle.net/j9Lguv1p/ I found this tutorial to be useful as well as fairly entertaining for canvas games http://www.crunchzilla.com/game-maven

Comment: @smcd Wow thank you